# Let a sequence be defined as $a_1\in \mathbb R$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+(1-2a)a_n+a^2$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Check the condition for convergence on a.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The original question looks like :

[image]

MY ATTEMPT:

I gave this question a glance [Proof that if $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+a_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861710/proof-that-if-a-1-1-and-a-n1-1-frac11a-n). From the very first answer I tried to draw some conclusion like this:

Since we will have $a_{n+1}=(a_n-a)^2+a_n$, that is if $f(x)=(x-a)^2+x$ then $|f'(x)|=2(x-a)+1\leq M$ for $M>0$.At the end I will have $\frac{2a-1-M}{2}\leq x\leq \frac{2a-1+M}{2}$, where M is arbitrarily small. So I can discard all the options and can claim (d) to be the correct one for some specific values of M. Also I observed that a is the only limit here.

Any help to do this question in a better way (between I am confused if I can do this question the way I mentioned above) .Thanks.

Comment: (a) and (b) don't make much sense to me.  What does "for n>1" refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=(x-a)^2+x$. Then, for each $x\in\Bbb R$, $f(x)\geqslant x$, and the equality $f(x)=x$ occurs when (and only when) $x=a$. Besides, $f(x)<a$ if and only if $x\in(a-1,a)$.

Since your sequence is defined so that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$, if $a_1\ne a$, then $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of real numbers. Furthermore, if that sequence converges to some limit $l$, then\begin{align}l&=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)\\&=f(l),\end{align}since $f$ is continuous. But $f(l)=l$ if and only if $l=a$. So:

1. If $a_1>a$, $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ diverges, because then $a<a_1<a_2<a_3<\cdots$, and therefore you cannot have $\lim_{n\to\infty}=a$.
2. If $a_1=a$ then $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, since $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):a_n=a$.
3. If $a_1\in(a-1,a)$, then $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, since it is strictly increasing and bounded (because $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):a_n<a$).
4. If $a_1=a-1$, then $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, since $a_n=a$ if $n>1$.
5. If $a_1<a-1$, then $a_2=f(a_1)>a$ and therefore $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ diverges: $a_n>a$ if $n>1$ and it is strictly increasing.

Therefore, the correct option is (c).

Comment: Thanks for the solution sir. How you specified that if $a_1>1$ then $(a_n)$ diverges?(I think it's a).

Comment: Yes, it is $a_1>a$. And I have add a justification. Is it clear to you?

Comment: Yes, it's clear now. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.